# Tablesorter live content from php sorting jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, tablesorter

I have a table that looks like this:

Title  | Price

A

B

C

I get the title from mysql and the price comes from php script.

My jquery for Price column looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
$(function() { 
var price = setInterval(function()
{
$('#A').load('live_price.php?title=A').fadeIn("slow");

},6000);
});
<script>
```

live_price.php does all the crunching and spits out a number.

Now, in this case, price update every 6 seconds and updates each row. My problem has to do with sorting this new content.

I tried using:

`$("table").trigger("update");` and

`$("table").trigger("sorton",[sorting]);` without any success. Please help

Answer (score 1):

[See here for the docs](http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-ajax.html).

I think you may just be forgetting to set the sorting order.

```
var sorting = [[2,1],[0,0]];
```

Before calling

```
$("table").trigger("sorton",[sorting]);
```

The other issue may be that .load is destroying all the data in the table. You may need to re-initialize the plugin every time after the table is populated with the new data.

Comment: I used var sorting = [[2,1],[0,0]]; and also did $('table').tablesorter(); at the end of my html, but that didn' do the trick.

Comment: Any errors in firebug? Also when are you calling $('table').tablesorter(); ? I only ask because there is an ajax sucess event and then an event for when its done manipulating the dom if I remember correctly. Of course you will want your code inside the done event rather than the ajax success event.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what you want is to use the "updateCell" method. It isn't documented, but it exists. I made a [blog post](http://wowmotty.blogspot.com/2011/06/jquery-tablesorter-missing-docs.html#methods) showing how to use it.

Also, if you are interested, I've forked a copy of [tablesorter on github](http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/docs/index.html) and made some improvements to the plugin. I even included automatically resorting the table after updates - here is the [updateCell demo page](http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/docs/example-update-cell.html) - click inside any cell in the "Total" column to see it work.